# Html form method post why?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Sorry I do not understand exactly how to ask this question but basically I noticed a lot of online examples using

```
<form method="post">
```

I have been creating all my forms without specifying "post" and just grabbing the data using c#. I would like to know what is the benefit of specifying the method post and submitting the form rather than just using c# to request the control values and then submitting the form through the code behind?

Sorry if this is not clear I tried my best to explain the question just a little confused.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29

Comment: Heh. The standard answer I get from interviewees when asking the difference between HTTP GET and POST: "Well, GET...gets. Whereas, POST...posts." Well, I can't argue with that! :)

Comment: Tim, did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `HTML` isn't pre-formated for `C#` only. Yes you can ommit it when using `C#` to request the control values, but when specifying `method='post'`, you ensure that your html code is cross-compatible.
It's your choice, but I really prefer using the `method='post'`, this is the most beautiful solution.

Answer (score 0):

The only benefit you get is that readers of your code don't have to guess what the default method is for the submit.  Looks like the default is post, and to specify that just takes away a little of the uncertainty for anyone reading the html later on, that's all.